# Indenting a shape into a model

Tags: maya

[image]
I want to use this 2d to indent my 3d mesh of a bottle to get a similar result to the example below

[image]

Thanks for the help been trying to work this one out for ages, if you have any other solutions that's fine, thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly no answers from Maya owners. I haven't one, but this is the way how the job is done in CAD software:

[image]

1. Place the wanted inset shape in front of the solid
2. Project the inset shape onto the solid
3. Take the extrude tool and push the projected shape a little inwards
4. The result

Altough this is a free version of commercial CAD program, the shape projection function is not disabled. For those programs which do not allow shape projections, there is another way:

- extrude the inset shape to a cylinder which goes inside the solid
- duplicate the solid and subtract it from the cylinder. Now the cylinder fits against the solid
- move the sylinder a little inside the solid
- subtract the cylinder from the solid => the inset is ready

Here's a reproduction of the second method:

[image]

1. Place the inset shape in front of the solid
2. Extrude the inset shape to a cylinder, let it go a little inside the solid
3. Make a spare copy of the solid, subtract the solid from the cylinder
4. Place the spare copy, move the cylinder to make it to intersect
5. Subtract the cylinder from the solid. Done.

NOTE: Step 3 is essential. If the solid has a thin wall, without step 3 it's difficult to avoid a hole:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that OP is using a polygon model, and polygon models are approximations of a limit surface, so now youd insetting a approximation with an approximation. And you get an approximation of a n approximation of an approximation.... So polygon modeling would need a totally different mental approach. And spending time explaining this would just be wasted effort.

Comment: @joojaa 1)thanks, but I am well aware the green bottle is is not a polygon mesh. But that does not prevent the boolean operations. 2)I do not see my writing as an effort. So you obviously write about your own.

Comment: Well i  have allready written >35,000 posts (sic) on 3D graphics (espeially maya) and i kindof allready decided to not do those again, ever. So if somebody wants a answer it really must somehow be a good question showing a lot of personal effort.

Comment: Also point is not that you cant not use booleans, the point is if your using booleans your doing something wrong, since thats not something a polygon modeler should ever do.

Comment: @joojaa not generally the decision I like, because the amount of characters you have typed into current answer as comments could well have been enough to bring the light to the questioner. I  also am interested in seeing it.

Comment: Oh no the answer is quite long.

Comment: @joojaa But I have an idea: The questioner has missed the point as soon as he lathed the main body and added the wings. He should have started from a cube or other simple form and then divide its surface to smaller and smaller polygons moving them towards the wanted the  surface form between the divisions. He probably would have got perfect looking output with doubling the number of polygons only 15 times or even less. At least it he did not have forgot to move all towards the wanted positions. I have seen (in videos) how someone models a perfect human head this way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67703/discussion-between-joojaa-and-user287001).